# Convert blob to file and upload to s3

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3

I am trying to convert a blob to a file but s3 doesn't return any error or results.

```
$('#frontPictureCropp').cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function(blob) {
            var file = new File([blob], imageId + '.png', {type: "image/png"});
            console.log(file);
             S3.upload({
                    files: file,
                    path:"IL"
                },function(e,r){
                    if(e)console.log(e);
                    if(r) {
                        console.log(r);
                    var imageData = [r._id, r.secure_url];

                    }
             });
        });
```

file in the console:
Thu Jan 19 2017 13:53:03 GMT+0200 (IST)
name
:
"HJ3ZnCq842EPKbnDx.png"
size
:
42562
type
:
"image/png"
webkitRelativePath
:
""